# Kubernetes Jupyter Server with Example Notebook and Persistent Storage

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, jupyter-lab

I am trying to run a jupyter lab server Kubernetes deployment with a docker container that is set up to be a Jupiter server and that contains an example notebook (and Jupyter config) in the jupyter working directory. I would like to link this working directory to persistent storage, but when mounting the (Azure fileshare) volume to the container (as specified in the deployement.yaml file), the example notebook gets deleted (due to the empty storage being mounted). Is there any way to mount the container and keep the notebook and config?

The deployment file looks more or less (with some unimportant sections replaced by '...')as follows:

`apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "api-chart.fullname" . }}
  labels:
  ...
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "api-chart.name" . }}
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
      ...
      volumes:
        - name: personal-volume
          azureFile:
            secretName: {{ .Values.sharedVolumes.personalSecretName }}
            shareName: personal
            readOnly: false
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: {{ .Values.service.targetPort }}
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: personal-volume
              mountPath: "/workspace"
              subPath: {{ .Values.username }}
          resources:
            ...`

Comment: Can you show your deployment?

Comment: try commenting out `subPath: {{ .Values.username }}`

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide much information on how you're mounting the storage service.  The first thing I would look is to make sure to use a StorageClass with the reclaim policy set to **Retain**.

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: azurefile
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=0
  - gid=0
  - mfsymlinks
  - cache=strict
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
reclaimPolicy: Retain
```

Comment: Will `reclaimPolicy: Retain` prevent the files in the container from being deleted when the volume is mounted? Is does not seem like it will.